# Sharing data in wifi direct on android devices

Tags: android, wifi, wifi-direct

I've been reading about WiFi direct in the last 2 days, found it very interesting feature to share data between devices with no intermediate access point.
I want to know if it's possible to share data between 2 devices where there's 3rd device connecting between them?

Example: If device A wants to share (send/receive) data with device B, is it  possible to connect to an intermediate device C to establish the connection and sharing the data? in this way the range between A to B can be increased with no interruptions.

Thanks.
Udi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible but not directly. You can establish a `WiFi Direct` link between `A` and `C` and also a link between `B` and `C`. What is missing is the forwarding of data between the 2 links in `C`. This is called `bridge`. You should be able to find android apps that do bridging.

Comment: @RobinKanters you can write the WiFi Direct driver by yourself as well for that matter :)

Comment: Somebody has to be the first one to write such an app ;)

Comment: thanks everyone for the comments.
it's very nice feature and we can do nice things with it. lets hope that Google will continue develop it in the next versions.